# EF core 5 Paging Performance issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core 5. I am trying to retrieve records from the table having 1 Million records. I would like to know how I can improve my performance.

Note: I have already implemented the index in the DB. I did google but not find any solution. please advice

How to improve Skip and Take performance in EF core 5

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsers(PaginationFilter filter)
        {
 **return await _context.User.AsNoTracking().Include(e => e.Roles)
                .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize)
                .Take(filter.PageSize)
                .ToListAsync<User>();**
}


public class PaginationFilter
    {
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public PaginationFilter()
        {
            this.PageNumber = 1;
            this.PageSize = 10;
        }
        public PaginationFilter(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            this.PageNumber = pageNumber < 1 ? 1 : pageNumber;
            this.PageSize = pageSize > 10 ? 10 : pageSize;
        }
    }




public static UsersPagedResponse<List<T>> CreateUsersPagedReponse<T>(List<T> pagedData, PaginationFilter validFilter, int totalRecords, IUriService uriService, string route)
        {
            var respose = new UsersPagedResponse<List<T>>(pagedData, validFilter.PageNumber, validFilter.PageSize);
            var totalPages = ((double)totalRecords / (double)validFilter.PageSize);
            int roundedTotalPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(totalPages));

            respose.MetaData = new MetaData()
            {
                Page = validFilter.PageNumber,
                PageSize = validFilter.PageSize,
                Links = new Links()
                {
                    Self = uriService.GetPageUri(new PaginationFilter(validFilter.PageNumber, validFilter.PageSize), route),
                    First = uriService.GetPageUri(new PaginationFilter(1, validFilter.PageSize), route),
                    Previous = validFilter.PageNumber - 1 >= 1 && validFilter.PageNumber <= roundedTotalPages ? uriService.GetPageUri(new PaginationFilter(validFilter.PageNumber - 1, validFilter.PageSize), route) : null,
                    Next = validFilter.PageNumber >= 1 && validFilter.PageNumber < roundedTotalPages ? uriService.GetPageUri(new PaginationFilter(validFilter.PageNumber + 1, validFilter.PageSize), route) : null,
                }
            };

            return respose;
        }
    }

public class UsersPagedResponse<T> : UsersResponse<T>
    {
        public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

        public UsersPagedResponse(T users, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            this.Users = users;
        }

        public UsersPagedResponse(T users)
        {
            this.Users = users;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `AsSplitQuery()`. In your case it may help.

Comment: *"I have already implemented the index in the DB"* On which field? Add `OrderBy` (for instance `.OrderBy(x => x.Id)`) **before** skip/take, otherwise EF Core adds something like `ORDER by 1`.

Comment: Also, do you have lazy loading enabled? Use an SQL Profiler to capture the query(queries) being executed and if those don't reveal something, execute those manually to check the execution plan. +1 on that you should always provide an `OrderBy` with pagination queries. The best way to maximize an EF query is to project the query down to a minimum viable view model using `Select`. This helps build efficient queries and ensures performance traps like lazy loading don't cripple you.